# Google Maps ambiguous use of a GMSMapViewType

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I just upgraded to Xcode 7.1. When I try to set the mapType of a GMSMapView I get the error Ambiguous use of 'kGMSTypeNormal', Ambiguous use of 'kGMSTypeTerrain', and Ambiguous use of 'kGMSTypeHybrid'.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

func myfunc() {
      if let myMapType = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(SettingsTableViewController.History.MapType) {
            switch myMapType {
            case "kGMSTypeNormal":
                mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
            case "kGMSTypeTerrain":
                mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeTerrain
            case "kGMSTypeHybrid":
                mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid
            default: break
                mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
            }
        } else {
            mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
        }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure why but putting "GoogleMaps." in front of all the kGMSTypes (i.e. GoogleMaps.kGMSTypeNormal) fixed the problem.

Comment: Solved my problem.

Comment: I suspect this happens because the enums are duplicated in some frameworks and when using GoogleMaps.kGMS... you are referencing the constant using its absolute and unmistakable identifier. Any way - this works.

Answer (score 2):

```
mapView.mapType = GMSMapViewType(rawValue: 1)!
```

- kGMSTypeNormal = 1
- kGMSTypeSatellite = 2
- kGMSTypeTerrain = 3
- kGMSTypeHybrid = 4
- kGMSTypeNone = 5

Answer (score 2):

here is the updated version

```
import UIKit      
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {
    var mapView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView = GMSMapView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        mapView.animate(toViewingAngle: 45)
        mapView.mapType = GMSMapViewType.satellite
        self.view = mapView


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Swift 3` use as bellow:

`.normal
.hybrid
.satellite
.terrain`

Answer (score 0):

If you open GMSMapViewType, you will see it defined as enum. In your switch statement, you're comparing it with strings which is wrong. You should better compare them with integers.

```
kGMSTypeNormal = 1
kGMSTypeSatellite = 2
kGMSTypeTerrain = 3
kGMSTypeHybrid = 4
kGMSTypeNone = 5
```

Comment: Doing  `let myMapType = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey(SettingsTableViewController.History.MapType)
        
        if myMapType == 1 {
                mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
        }` still gives me the same error. In fact, i'm unable to define the mapType anywhere in the class as it just comes up as being ambiguous.

Comment: let myMapType = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey(SettingsTableViewController.‌​History.MapType). What value do you get on myMapType?

Comment: It is an Int. Xcode complains about this at compile time.

Comment: I don't see any problem with this: if myMapType == 1 { mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal }. So you must check this let myMapType = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey(SettingsTableViewController.‌​History.MapType)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like this

`mapView.mapType = GoogleMaps.kGMSTypeSatellite`